# Converting server side cookie to client side

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, cookies

Using Spring MVC, whenever I logged into my site, it creates a cookie `JSESSIONID` I can get its value from firebug's Resources > Cookies. But I am not able to get this cookie value from javascript.

What settings/code I need to create a new client side cookie (that I can access via javascript) from the server side cookie.

Comment: The cookie might have the HttpOnly flag set forbidding JavaScript to access it (check with firebug, etc.) - and you **do not want** to remove the HttpOnly flag from a session cookie! See e.g. this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html

Comment: I think you've nailed it. You want to create a client side value, from a value on the server. From the client's perspective, that isn't possible!

Comment: Let's assume server put cookie `JSESSIONID="true"` to `/login/user` path. If you ask `document.cookie` from browser on `/` or `/login` url, you cannot see `JSESSIONID` cookie, but you can see `/` or `/login` path related other cookies. So, check/compare your cookies `path` from Resources > Cookies with client side browser url which you're asking cookie from JavaScript.